# Can I submit my paper to arXiv with a header that says "Under review at X" when it isn't?

Tags: ethics, paper-submission, arxiv

Previously I submitted my paper in MS Word format to arXiv.  Now after almost two years, I decided to submit an updated version in LaTeX format.

To create the LaTeX version of the document, I downloaded a template from [here](https://github.com/wk910930/paper-template/tree/master/ICLR/iclr_2016) that added a line at the top of each page saying:

> Under review as a conference paper at ICLR 2016

Do I have to remove that notice, or is it OK to leave it as is?

Comment: (Off-topic: The balance upvote for the answer / upvote for the question is really surprising.... How could an answer be so good if the question is so terrible? I don't get it.)

Comment: Was your paper ever even remotely related to that conference?

Comment: (@Clément As much as it's not "proper" I imagine it's a lot of "you shouldn't need to ask this, I doubt it will help anybody in future", and then "but since you did - this is definitively the correct thing do to")

Comment: @pipe: I guess it was.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Remove it.  It is not appropriate to mislead people as to the submission or publication status of your paper.  You should also remove any other reference to the conference appearing in the paper (e.g. a logo).

Additionally, you'll have to upload your LaTeX source to arXiv in order to have it posted, including the conference style file, so you should make sure its copyright allows this.

(Even if you really had submitted the paper to that conference, you typically wouldn't acknowledge this in the preprint.  The reason is simple: if the paper isn't actually published in that conference, people will be able to infer that it must have been rejected, and this is something you'd probably rather were not publicly known.)

Update: [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105429/how-can-i-prove-that-my-article-has-not-been-submitted-to-another-journal) is a question from someone who used a template that included the name of Journal X when submitting to Journal Y, and had the paper rejected on suspicion of double submission.  While I think that Journal Y was out of line in doing this, it does illustrate that these sort of misunderstandings can have serious consequences.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I remove that part, there wont be anything left to indicate ICLR. its just a simple latex format. here is the example template which I used : https://github.com/wk910930/paper-template/tree/master/ICLR/iclr_2016 
and I also added some new packages as well. the shape of the tables are also changed. do you think this is enough knowing that there will be no indication of ICLR to mislead anyone?

Comment: I'm glad I asked this before doing anything. by the way, to make things more clear for myself and possibly other newbies as well, does under review mean that the paper is accepted ?
the reason I'm asking is that initially I thought , anyone can submit to any conference, and get reviewed, and then get rejected or accepted. so if a paper is under review, it doesn't mean anything. Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: @Breeze Nope, under review means just that: It's under review. It doesnt mean nothing.
Still, you can't pretend it is, if it's not.

Comment: @Breeze: Another possible source of trouble is if the paper had been accepted in another conference before 2016, or if you actually submitted it to a different conference at the same time.  Then people would suspect you of  [double submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/why-should-the-scientific-community-avoid-double-submissions) which is considered highly unethical, and this could lead to a lot of problems for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. No I have not participated in any conferences yet, that's why I have zero knowledge concerning this kind of stuff.  
Actually I was looking for a simple laTex template that I could use to convert my previous work to Latex. Both as a practice and also have my paper look a bit more professional (MS word seem to be frowned upon in academic world and people refuse to trust papers that use MS word!) So I searched for templates. Some were very complex and others like NIPS and this ICLR templates were very simple. I never intended on misleading anyone. God Bless you guys :)

Comment: ICLR 2016 had an interesting reviewing process where all submitted papers and their reviews are public and allowed anybody to comment on it.  So, you can't really hide that your paper was submitted there and rejected.

Comment: @Breeze There are a lot of simple LaTeX templates out there. Some of them, like the one you found are made for specific conferences or journals or so on; others are general-purpose. So you just need to find a good general one. [tex.SE] (perhaps in the chat room) would be a reasonable place to ask for help with that.

Comment: @DavidZ: Thank you very much. Actually this answer and all the comments I got was very helpful to me. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: @waldol1: Obviously, that was not my intention at all. if it were I wouldn't be asking here. I "thought" having the under review term would not give any merit to work(anyone could submit and get reviewed, so up till then I thought it would not be a big deal), unlike the term "Accepted as a conference paper at xxx" which says otherwise. but I got skeptical and asked to make sure if this is right or not. Thanks to dear God and you guys I got my answer before getting myself into trouble.

Comment: Generally speaking, academia places a high value on honesty. You know it's not true and therefore you shouldn't say it.  Whether or not it gives any "merit" is irrelevant.  Just don't lie.

Comment: @NateEldredge Though I agree with the general point of your comment about the high value of honesty, I think "irrelevant" might be too strong. Lying is bad, but lying to claim undeserved "merit" is even worse.